# 2008R2 DHCP Server Becomes Unresponsive

Tags: windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

At the end of 2013, our single Windows Server 2008R2 DHCP server started becoming unresponsive once every week or so.  The server itself was up, but the DHCP server was unresponsive.  Attempts to connect to the management interface would hang and never time out, and attempts to restart the service from services.msc would hang as well.  No entries were written to the dhcp log, and there was nothing helpful in any event log.  I read several microsoft kb articles about similar issues and installed a hotpatch that I found but none of that helped.  After a few weeks of this happening, and bouncing the entire server to resolve it each time, we migrated most of the scopes to a second server, and even though this didn't resolve our issue, it did mitigate the problem.  The issue never reappeared on that server, and with most scopes migrated it was still serving DHCP leases on a scope of 500+.  At that time we theorized that while there is no official limit to the capacity of the Windows DHCP server that perhaps we had encountered some sort of race condition relevant to the number of leases we had at any one time.

Two days ago the same thing happened on the second server, and it happened again this morning.  I was not in the office when it happened on Monday, so the Linux admin bounced the entire server (which was the only thing that helped previously).  This morning when it happened I was online so I jumped in.  After attempting all of the things we tried in 2013, I used taskmanager to force kill the svchost that was running dhcpserver, and then was able to restart the service using services.msc.  An entry was then written to the dhcp log indicating that the service was online again, however it never started handing out IPs.  The management interface was responsive also at this point.  After almost an hour of poking at it, I had to reboot the server so that people coming in to start their day wouldn't be inconvenienced.

We have not added any new scopes or changed the network in any significant way that I could see would cause the issue to appear.

At this point I'm hoping to find a way to increase the logging that DHCP server does, although I'm wondering if it's more than the DHCP server service causing the issue at this point, since I was able to force kill it and restart it, and it wrote to the audit log, but then nothing else ever happened.

The servers are running Kaspersky AV, and all the exclusions for DHCP servers that I found online are in place (which was basically excluding the dhcp folder) however I did uninstall it this morning to see if that makes a difference.

Server is mostly patched, it's not 100% up to date but it is very close.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

Comment: What do you have your Lease time set to?

Comment: Different scopes have different lease times, scopes for wireless networks are all set to 4 hours, scopes for desktops are set to 3 and 4 days.

Comment: How many wireless DHCP clients do you have?

Comment: Around 200 across two scopes.

Comment: So you have 200 wireless clients all trying to renew their leases every 2 hours, based on the T1 renewal timer of the DHCP client. I might suggest running a packet capture on the server and filtering it for DHCP traffic. Then when the issue occurs see if the capture shows a high volume of DHCP client renewal traffic. Also, have a read here for details on the Renewal/Rebinding process: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DHCPLeaseRenewalandRebindingProcesses-2.htm

Comment: I am happy to read on this, however this has not been a problem before and has been setup this way for a while, I cannot bring myself to believe that this is the cause of the issue.  The issue arose this morning before anyone was in the building, so there were only about 12 active leases at the time.

Comment: `1.` The presence of the users has no bearing on the DHCP process, unless all of their computers were turned off until they arrived. If the computers are turned on then the DHCP process will be "in process". `2.` I understand your reticence based on the fact that this is a "new" problem but unless you rule it out... you can't rule it out. Ignoring a potential cause because we don't believe it could be the cause doesn't allow us to rule it out as the cause. You have to prove that this isn't the problem as much as you have to prove that it is the problem.

Comment: Those two scopes serve wireless devices, almost all of which are gone with the users in the evening.  I'm going to leave Wireshark running per your suggestion and we will see what happens.  I definitely appreciate your thoughts.